# Is there a way to programmatically add a description to individual questions in a Google Form that is generated using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-workspace

I am trying to find a way to take text from a spreadsheet and use it to add context to individual questions in a Google Form.  When manually making a Google Form you can add a description to individual questions, but I cannot find a way to do this programmatically.

Currently I can programmatically generate a form from a sheet, but the only way I have found so far to insert the text into the form is by putting the data into the form as either the title of a question (which then generates obscenely large header cells in the sheet that collects the answers) or as a header title (which breaks the form up in a way that I do not want).  If this helps, it is not necessary for the inserted text to be logically connected with the question as long as it can be inserted in a way that it is visually connected with the question to the user.

Currently I have this:

```
function getRequests() {

  for (var i = 2; i <= requestLastRow; i++) {

    var name = requestSheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
    var email = requestSheet.getRange(i,2).getValue(); 
    var supervisor = requestSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    var start = requestSheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
    var formattedStart = Utilities.formatDate(start, 'EST', 'EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa');
    var end = requestSheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    var formattedEnd = Utilities.formatDate(end, 'EST', 'EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa');
    var hours = requestSheet.getRange(i,7).getValue();
    var comment = requestSheet.getRange(i,8).getValue();

    var item = approvalForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle("Name: " + name +
                  "\n\nEmail: " + email +
                  "\n\nSupervisor: " + supervisor +
                  "\n\nStart Date: " + formattedStart +
                  "\n\nEnd Date: " + formattedEnd +
                  "\n\nHours Requested: " + hours +
                  "\n\nComments: " + comment)
                  .setChoices([item.createChoice('Approve'), item.createChoice('Deny')]);

    var section = approvalForm.addPageBreakItem(); 
  }
}
```

Which generates this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.setHelpText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item.html#sethelptexttext).

> Sets the item's help text (sometimes called description text for layout items like ImageItems, PageBreakItems, and SectionHeaderItems).

```
var item = approvalForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
item.setHelpText("Name: " + name +
                 "\n\nEmail: " + email +
                 "\n\nSupervisor: " + supervisor +
                 "\n\nStart Date: " + formattedStart +
                 "\n\nEnd Date: " + formattedEnd +
                 "\n\nHours Requested: " + hours +
                 "\n\nComments: " + comment)
                 .setChoices([item.createChoice('Approve'), item.createChoice('Deny')]);
```